# How to access the Azure App service using organisation VPN without VPN Client and Virtual Machine?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have created my project pipeline in the Azure DevOps, and the same has been deployed into the Azure App Service using Tomcat-Server.

I could access the app with the link provided by the app service with public Ip.

But I need to access the app using my organization's VPN from anywhere by just turning on the VPN without using the VPN client and Virtual Machine.

I have created the private endpoint, site-to-site VPN configuration everything, and the IP of this has also been mapped to my organization firewall. The connection has been established successfully, but I cannot connect with the app service using my organization's VPN.

So, could you please help me with this?

Comment: Think more from AD  and ADB2B.  then use policies and roles

Comment: Ok let me try with that